# Sqlite INSERT OR REPLACE vs PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sqlite, replace, insert, primary-key

Using sqlite

I need to insert an entire record. If it already exists the record should be ignored.

If I use the command below, informing the "id_key" number, it works as expected:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO contatos ('id_key', 'VERSION', 'FN', 'N', 'EMAIL') 
VALUES (209, '2.1', 'bla bla', 'bla;bla;;;', 'bla@x.com');
```

But how do I reproduce this behavior without informing a value for the "id_key" field, which is auto-incrementing. If I use the code like this, it repeats the data if it already exists:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO contatos ('id_key', 'VERSION', 'FN', 'N', 'EMAIL') 
VALUES (NULL, '2.1', 'bla bla', 'bla;bla;;;', 'bla@x.com');
```

my table:

```
CREATE TABLE "contatos" (
    "id_key"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "VERSION"   TEXT,
    "FN"    TEXT,
    "N" TEXT,
    "EMAIL" TEXT,
    "TEL;WORK"  TEXT,
    "TEL;HOME"  TEXT,
    "TEL;CELL"  TEXT,
    "PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;JPEG"    TEXT,
    "EMAIL;HOME"    TEXT,
    "ADR;HOME"  TEXT,
    "TEL;VOICE" TEXT,
    "TEL;PREF"  TEXT,
    "TEL;X-Celular" TEXT,
    "EMAIL;PREF"    TEXT,
    "TEL;X-Antigo"  TEXT,
    "ORG"   TEXT,
    "TEL;X-WhatsApp"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id_key" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want the combination of the columns `VERSION`, `FN`, `N` and `EMAIL` to be unique.
For this, you need a `UNIQUE` constraint in the table's definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "contatos" (
    "id_key"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "VERSION"   TEXT,
    "FN"    TEXT,
    "N" TEXT,
    "EMAIL" TEXT,
    "TEL;WORK"  TEXT,
    "TEL;HOME"  TEXT,
    "TEL;CELL"  TEXT,
    "PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;JPEG"    TEXT,
    "EMAIL;HOME"    TEXT,
    "ADR;HOME"  TEXT,
    "TEL;VOICE" TEXT,
    "TEL;PREF"  TEXT,
    "TEL;X-Celular" TEXT,
    "EMAIL;PREF"    TEXT,
    "TEL;X-Antigo"  TEXT,
    "ORG"   TEXT,
    "TEL;X-WhatsApp"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id_key" AUTOINCREMENT),
    UNIQUE(VERSION, FN, N, EMAIL)
);
```

and then use `INSERT OR IGNORE` to insert new rows, without using the `id_key`:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO contatos (VERSION, FN, N, EMAIL) 
VALUES ('2.1', 'bla bla', 'bla;bla;;;', 'bla@x.com');
```

or `INSERT OR REPLACE` if you want the existing row with the same combination of the 4 columns to be deleted and the new one inserted:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO contatos (VERSION, FN, N, EMAIL) 
VALUES ('2.1', 'bla bla', 'bla;bla;;;', 'bla@x.com');
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0bbceda2ac52d4f2e20a1af3659099aa).

Comment: That wouldn't be it, it's not possible to use Unique.

Comment: @Leonardoxxx why?